# Google cloud scp permission denied

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, scp, permission-denied

I am trying to transfer files to my Google cloud hosted Linux (Debian) instance via secure copy (scp). I did exactly what the documentation told to connect from a local machine to the instance. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance.

- Created a SSH keygen
- Added the keygen to my instance

I can login successfully by:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-keygen [USERNAME]@[IP]
```

But when I want to copy files to the instance I get a message "permission denied".

```
scp -r -i ~/.ssh/my-keygen /path/to/directory/ [USERNAME]@[IP]:/var/www/html/
```

[image: Permission denied]

It looks like the user with which I login has no permissions to write files, so I already tried to change the file permissions of /var/www/, but this still gives the permission denied message.

I also tried to add the user to the root group, but this still gives the same problem.

```
usermod -G root myuser
```

Comment: Verify the problem with command SCP or with user permissions, try SCP file to different directory(/tmp/ or user home directory) on server.

Comment: @BalajiReddy I tried what you said, but get the same permission denied messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command line should be

```
scp -r -i ~/.ssh/my-keygen /path/to/directory/ [USERNAME]@[IP]:/var/www/html/
```

Assuming your files are in the local `/path/to/directory/` and the `/var/www/html/` is on the remote server.

The permissions does not allow to write in the `/var/www/html/`. Writing to `/tmp/` should work. Then you can copy the files with `sudo` to the desired destination with `root` privileges.

Comment: Sorry, this was carelessness in my question, but not the problem. I have edited my question.

Comment: So what are the permissions? `ls -ld /var/www/html/`?

Comment: Hmm.. those are: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 12:52 /var/www/html/`

Comment: So that is obvious. Unless your `[USERNAME]` is `root`, you don't have write access to this directory. Either copy the files into some `/tmp/`, where you have access and then move them to `/var/www/` as a `root` or give your user (or group) `write` permissions.

Comment: I was able to transfer the files to `/tmp/` and I will try to add the user to the root group. Maybe you could edit your answer so I could approve it.

Answer (score 0):

If SSH isn't working, install gcloud CLI and run the following locally: `gcloud compute scp --recurse /path/to/directory [IP] --tunnel-through-iap`. This will dump the directory into your `/home/[USERNAME]/` folder. Then log into the console and use `sudo` to move the directory to /var/www/html/.

For documentation, see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp.